# problem in configureFlutterEngine method writing kotlin code in flutter

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, flutter

I wanted to write platform specific code in flutter, according to the flutter documentation we should override **configureFlutterEngine** method like code snippet below:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
      // TODO
    }
  }
```

but when I pass **flutterEngine** to **GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith()**, It says:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is FlutterEngine but PluginRegistry! was expected

I've already checked link below in github but didn't find any solution working for me.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45231

here is the link of flutter documentation for writing platform specific code.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab#example-project

Answer (score 5):

Instead of **configureFlutterEngine()** method, I used **onCreate()** and now is working fine.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
      // TODO
    }
  }
```

Instead of passing `flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger` to `MethodChannel`, pass `flutterView`.

Comment: How to get FlutterView ? It also gives error at registerWith(this)

Comment: An explanation for how to get flutterView would be helpful.

Comment: An explanation for how to get flutterView would be helpful. –

Answer (score 5):

This is how I used it in kotlin

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
      // TODO
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to use **same imports** as shown. [Read Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation)

Comment: @Zohab Ali   For me configureFlutterEngine it's not calling. Any idea what can be an issue. Followed the same steps as above.