# Flutter - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.App8.Name/com.App8.Name.MainActivity}: Could not instantiate FlutterFragment subclass

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've facing this issue when I run or build with release mode. Below I have attached the error lines & my codes for replicating this error.

Other other modes seems working fine only thing I face issue with release build, What will be the cause can anybody help me on this to figure it out.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.App8.Whistle/com.App8.Whistle.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate FlutterFragment subclass (io.flutter.embedding.android.b)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.App8.Whistle

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "flavor").setMethodCallHandler {
                _, result -> result.success(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="${applicationName}" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.App8.Whistle"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "flavor"
    productFlavors{
        dev{
            dimension "flavor"
            resValue "string","app_name","App8 Whist Dev"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix " Dev"
        }
        qa{
            dimension "flavor"
            resValue "string","app_name","App8 Whist QA"
            applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
            versionNameSuffix " Qa"     
            
        }
        prod{
            dimension "flavor"
            resValue "string","app_name","App8 Whist"
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.App8.Whistle'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: This Stack overflow answer helped me figure it out. Very Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67969845/10174037